# Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output

Tags: cordova

What happens is that I put the command $cordova build android at the command prompt and it gives me this error:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: downloads.gradle.org
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: downloads.gradle.org
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2661)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2583)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1769)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)'
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Jdk version(1.8) and make sure you add environment variables for jdk. After you set restart the visual studio and build your project.

Comment: I tried it, but call me the following message:
<pre> C:\Users>java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

C:\Users>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51

C:\Users> <pre>
And it does not work
PD: I'm using the cordova, no the visual studio.